# Detection inside component if i have ngIf on some elements?

Tags: angular

I want to detect if i clicked inside component but i have some part where i use ngIf to show or hide some elements and thats the problem because it not see that element at the moment and i get false. Any suggestion how can i fix that?

```
 handleClick(event){
        var clickedComponent = event.target;
        console.log(event.target,'adsadasdas');
        var inside = false;
        do {
            if (clickedComponent === this._eref.nativeElement) {
                inside = true;
            }
            clickedComponent = clickedComponent.parentNode;
        } while (clickedComponent);
        if(inside){
            console.log('inside');
        }else{
            console.log('outside');
        }
    }
```

I have sidebar component. Inside sidebar i have this:

```
<default-block head="Podaci o korisniku" class="z-col-24" block="blockgroup" [(visible)]="isCustomerVisible || getFromModal" [mainBlock] = "isVisibleBackCa"  [additionalItems]="true" (buttonClick)="getFromHistory()"
                        (openModal)="showModal($event)"  [ngClass]="{disabledCa: disabled}">


                        <div default-block="body" class="contact-body pointer">
                            <div class="contact-body-wrapper" dnd-draggable  [dragData]="customerGeneralInfo" (onDragStart)="dnd.set(true);" (onDragEnd)="dnd.set(false)" >
                                <span class="inline" *ngIf="customerGeneralInfo?.customerinfo?.lastname">
                                    <div class="z-inputs" >
                                        <label>Korisnik</label>
                                        <span disabled class="textarea"> {{customerGeneralInfo?.customerinfo?.lastname}} </span>
                                    </div>
                                </span>
                                <span class="inline" *ngIf="customerGeneralInfo?.customertypeName">
                                    <div class="z-inputs">
                                        <label>Tip</label>
                                        <input class="readonly"  [ngModel]="customerGeneralInfo?.customertypeName" type="text" disabled>
                                    </div>
                                </span>
                                <span class="inline" *ngIf="customerGeneralInfo?.customerstypeName">
                                    <div class="z-inputs">
                                        <label>Podtip</label>
                                        <span class="textarea">{{customerGeneralInfo?.customerstypeName}}</span>
                                    </div>
                                </span>
                                <span class="inline" *ngIf="customerGeneralInfo?.parentName">
                                    <div class="z-inputs">
                                        <label>Parent</label>
                                        <span class="textarea" disabled>{{customerGeneralInfo?.parentName}}</span>
                                    </div>
                                </span>
                                <span class="inline" *ngIf="customerGeneralInfo?.headName">
                                    <div class="z-inputs">
                                        <label>Nosilac hijerarhije</label>
                                        <span class="textarea" disabled >{{customerGeneralInfo?.headName}}</span>
                                    </div>
                                </span>
                                <span class="inline" *ngIf="customerGeneralInfo?.activationdate">
                                    <div class="z-inputs">
                                        <label>Datum aktivacije korisnika</label>
                                        <input class="readonly"  [ngModel]="customerGeneralInfo?.activationdate | date:'dd.MM.yyyy'"  type="text" disabled>
                                    </div>
                                </span>
                                <span class="inline" *ngIf="customerGeneralInfo?.terminationdate">
                                    <div class="z-inputs">
                                        <label>Datum isključenja korisnika</label>
                                        <input class="readonly"  [ngModel]="customerGeneralInfo?.terminationdate | date:'dd.MM.yyyy'" type="text" disabled>
                                    </div>
                                </span>
                                <span class="inline" *ngIf="customerGeneralInfo?.description">
                                    <div class="z-inputs">
                                        <label>Razlog isključenja korisnika</label>
                                        <input class="readonly" [ngModel]="customerGeneralInfo?.description" type="text" disabled>
                                    </div>
                                </span>
                            </div>
</default-block>
```

I have multiple of this `<default-block>` where i have visible true or false that works with ngIf. Now when i click on somem meni on sidebar i will show that block inside sidebar component. Problem is when i switch between those blocks because they are hidden event.target is false and then it always detect "outside" event.

Answer (score 0):

use @ViewChild for elemen refs. Examples and usage [here](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild)

Comment: Thanks for the update. On First glance, try to use *ngIf instead of Visible properties too: that is [not recommended](http://angularjs.blogspot.hu/2016/04/5-rookie-mistakes-to-avoid-with-angular.html) in Angular anymore. Maybe not mixing them will solve the problem.

Comment: visible is only input and then on that component im using hidden class where i hide or show .. with display:none just like ngIf does

Comment: Just a minor correction to the last comment, ngIf removes the element completely from the DOM, so that should be more efficient that making the element invisible. See https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#why-remove-rather-than-hide